# Dealing with large JSON response from web and using it into SearchView with RecyclerView/ListView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-listview, searchview

I have JSON response similar to the following,

```
{"data":
  [
    {"matcd":"610016","matdesc":"Billet gade C20"},
    {"matcd":"402100","matdesc":"Hot Metal"}
    .
    .
    .

  ]
}
```

The JSON array contains more than **100,000** items.
My requirement is to build an android activity that can search and filter these items by exploiting *SearchView* and *RecyclerView* or *ListView*.

**My efforts**

I have stored this JSON in *SharedPreferences* using a background *AsyncTask*. I then used JSON parser to add filtered items to a *ListView* on *onQueryTextSubmit* event of my *SearchView*.

Everything works fine if my JSON contains items less than 1000. But I see a huge performance issue for my original JSON (>100,000).

I haven't tried *SQLite* yet. But, I am not sure if it will work with that too.

If anyone of you has dealt with such scenarios, please guide me on what should be the best practice to follow in order to avoid any performance issue.

Comment: Ideally, this searching should be performed at the cloud side... 
Can you please  give more context when you are fetching this much data?

Comment: I tried cloud site, but searching at cloud site requires an AsysncTask which again reduce performance. So, I thought, maybe I can put everything in the device itself through a background AsyncTask and later on I can have a faster search from the device directly.

Comment: An async task will not reduce performance. And servers mostly search faster than your Android code.

Comment: We do not know how you search for json items. You did not tell. If uou put all in an indexed db your searches will go quick.

Comment: Searching via APi call will be much faster.. From app side, it will be 1 network call then Cloud will give all data...   

while when you do on app side, you have to first fetch these many data and store in local ( DB or shared Pref)   and perform filter on these data..

Comment: I agree with KishanMaurya and blackapps. In my case server is taking too many authentication and authorization checks before responding to the client that is slowing down my performance and is not getting any fruitful onQueryTextChange event.

Comment: @blackapps, currently, I am doing text based search using contains() function. I am going to try DB and indexed based as suggested by you using SQLite.

Comment: `have stored this JSON in SharedPreferences` That does not look a good idea to begin with. Better store all in a file in getFilesDir().